# Angularjs cannot get data from service

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I'm trying to pass data from one controller to another using a service, however no matter what I'm trying it always returns 'undefined' on the second controller. Here is my service :

```
app.service('myService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
 var savedData = {}

 this.setData = function (data) {
   savedData = data;
   console.log('Data saved !', savedData);
 }

 this.getData = function get() {
     console.log('Data used !', savedData);
  return this.savedData;
 }
}]);
```

Here is controller1 :

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope','$location','$firebaseSimpleLogin','myService','$cookies','$window', function($scope,$location, $firebaseSimpleLogin, myService, $cookies, $window) {
loginObj.$login('password', {
            email: username,
            password: password
        })
        .then(function(user) {
            // Success callback
            console.log('Authentication successful');
            myService.setData(user);
            console.log('myservice:', myService.getData()); // works fine
}]);
```

And then controller2:

```
// Dashboard controller
.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseSimpleLogin','myService',function($scope,$firebaseSimpleLogin, $location, myService) {

    console.log('myservice:', myService.getData()); //returns undefined

}]);
```

That is simple code, unfortunately I've been struggling for a few hours now, any suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get `Data used !` in the console as well?

Comment: The only difference I see is that in the first example, the `setData` method is called inside a `then` block. Can you try that in the second controller?

Comment: Yes, I get     Data used !   in the console when using it from controller1, but not from controller2. And I've tried to get the data in     then    block as well, as the result of the same request as in controller1, that is still not working.

Comment: Created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/frishi/8yn3nhfw/16/
To isolate the problem, can you remove the dependencies from the definition for `myService`  and see if that makes it work? Look at the console after you load the fiddle.

Comment: It would also help to see how you have bootstrapped your angular app. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Yes removing the dependencies actually worked, thanks a lot ! The issue was coming from the $location dependency ! Many thanks again.

Comment: I added my comment as the answer, feel free to accept it, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a fiddle here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/frishi/8yn3nhfw/16

To isolate the problem, can you remove the dependencies from the definition for myService and see if that makes it work? Look at the console after you load the fiddle.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.service('myService', function(){
    this.getData = function(){
   return "got Data";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the issue is that you are returning `this.savedData` in the service. Try returning `savedData`.

`this` behaves different in Javascript than in other languages.

Comment: Even without the this. it does not work, I've actually added it after reading other posts on the subject but it did not change the result.